# Want to convert String into json object in flutter

Tags: flutter

[{insert: comming comming}, {insert:
, attributes: {list: ordered}}]

getting this string response from backend. I want to convert it in a json object , not in json string.
I am using flutterQuill editor for rich text , so I want the string as json object , so that I can use it on the flutter quill

Answer (score 0):

you should read this:

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json

Basic JSON serialization in Flutter is very simple. Flutter has a built-in dart:convert library that includes a straightforward JSON encoder and decoder.

There are also examples.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the official flutter Docs? This is the link: [dart-convert -jsonEncode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html)

In there, you can find how it is done.

Comment: Yes I have checked that also . But the jsonEncode will convert the string in json string. I got response "[{insert: comming comming}, {insert: , attributes: {list: ordered}}]" , which is already a string. But I want to convert the string as json object. I mean List<dynamic> type.    var encode = json.encode(textwill['description']) - this is my code sample. I want to convert the string as list dynamic using jsonDecode function

Comment: QuillEditor(
                          controller: QuillController(
                            document: Document.fromJson(
                                jsonDecode(textwill['description'])),
                            selection: const TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0),
                          ),
                        )),